# Strange `ErrorType` error referencing columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given the following pandas Dataframe `df` -

| **Reporting Group** | **Entity/Grouping** | **Entity ID** | **Adjusted Value (Today, No Div, USD)** | **Adjusted TWR (Current Quarter, No Div, USD)** | **Adjusted TWR (YTD, No Div, USD)** | **Annualized Adjusted TWR (Since Inception, No Div, USD)** | **Adjusted Value (No Div, USD)** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Barrack Family | William and Rupert Trust | 9957007 | -1.44 |  |  |  | -1.44 |
| Barrack Family | Cash | - | -1.44 |  |  |  | -1.44 |
| Barrack Family | Gratia Holdings No. 2 LLC | 8413655 | 55491732.66 | -0.971018847 | -0.971018847 | 11.52490309 | 55491732.66 |
| Barrack Family | Investment Grade Fixed Income | - | 18469768.6 |  |  |  | 18469768.6 |
| Barrack Family | High Yield Fixed Income | - | 3668982.44 | -0.205356545 | -0.205356545 | 4.441190127 | 3668982.44 |

I am trying to only keep rows that where `Entity/Grouping` column values == `Cash` **AND** where any of the following column values are `NaN` -

- `Adjusted TWR (Current Quarter, No Div, USD)`
- `Adjusted TWR (YTD, No Div, USD)`
- `Annualized Adjusted TWR (Since Inception, No Div, USD)`

**Current code:** the following function takes `df` and tries to perform the above said and return, ready for use in another function -

```
def twr_exceptions_logic():
    df = databases_creation()

    df  = df.loc[(df['Entity/Grouping']!= 'Cash')]
    df  = df.loc[(df['Adjusted TWR (Current Quarter, No Div, USD)',
                              'Adjusted TWR (YTD, No Div, USD)',
                              'Annualized Adjusted TWR (Since Inception, No Div, USD)'].isnull())]
    return df
```

**Issue/Error:** currently, I am getting a non-descript `TypeError`, which references the columns I am referencing:
`KeyError: ('Adjusted TWR (Current Quarter, No Div, USD)', 'Adjusted TWR (YTD, No Div, USD)', 'Annualized Adjusted TWR (Since Inception, No Div, USD)')`

**Help:** Am I missing something obvious? Do I have an obvious syntax error? Any hints/tips would be warmly received.

Comment: You wrote "I am trying to only keep rows that where `Entity/Grouping` column values == `Cash`", while in your code you wrote `df = df.loc[(df['Entity/Grouping']!= 'Cash')]`. It is confusing for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need one more square bracket.
2. You can use `any` method to make a proper condition.

### Code:

```py
import pandas as pd

def databases_creation():
    import numpy as np
    return pd.DataFrame({'Reporting Group': {0: 'Barrack Family', 1: 'Barrack Family', 2: 'Barrack Family', 3: 'Barrack Family', 4: 'Barrack Family'}, 'Entity/Grouping': {0: 'William and Rupert Trust', 1: 'Cash', 2: 'Gratia Holdings No. 2 LLC', 3: 'Investment Grade Fixed Income', 4: 'High Yield Fixed Income'}, 'Entity ID': {0: '9957007', 1: '-', 2: '8413655', 3: '-', 4: '-'}, 'Adjusted Value (Today, No Div, USD)': {0: -1.44, 1: -1.44, 2: 55491732.66, 3: 18469768.6, 4: 3668982.44}, 'Adjusted TWR (Current Quarter, No Div, USD)': {0: np.NaN, 1: np.NaN, 2: -0.971018847, 3: np.NaN, 4: -0.205356545}, 'Adjusted TWR (YTD, No Div, USD)': {0: np.NaN, 1: np.NaN, 2: -0.971018847, 3: np.NaN, 4: -0.205356545}, 'Annualized Adjusted TWR (Since Inception, No Div, USD)': {0: np.NaN, 1: np.NaN, 2: 11.52490309, 3: np.NaN, 4: 4.441190127}, 'Adjusted Value (No Div, USD)': {0: -1.44, 1: -1.44, 2: 55491732.66, 3: 18469768.6, 4: 3668982.44}})

def twr_exceptions_logic():
    df = databases_creation()

    # df  = df.loc[(df['Entity/Grouping']!= 'Cash')]
    # df  = df.loc[(df['Adjusted TWR (Current Quarter, No Div, USD)',
    #                           'Adjusted TWR (YTD, No Div, USD)',
    #                           'Annualized Adjusted TWR (Since Inception, No Div, USD)'].isnull())]

    mask = (df['Entity/Grouping']!= 'Cash') & (df[['Adjusted TWR (Current Quarter, No Div, USD)',
                              'Adjusted TWR (YTD, No Div, USD)',
                              'Annualized Adjusted TWR (Since Inception, No Div, USD)']].isnull().any(axis=1))
    df  = df[mask]

    return df

df = twr_exceptions_logic()

print(df)
```

### Output:

| Reporting Group | Entity/Grouping | Entity ID | Adjusted Value (Today, No Div, USD) | Adjusted TWR (Current Quarter, No Div, USD) | Adjusted TWR (YTD, No Div, USD) | Annualized Adjusted TWR (Since Inception, No Div, USD) | Adjusted Value (No Div, USD) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Barrack Family | William and Rupert Trust | 9957007 | -1.44 | nan | nan | nan | -1.44 |
| Barrack Family | Investment Grade Fixed Income | - | 1.84698e+07 | nan | nan | nan | 1.84698e+07 |

Answer (score 1):

You need a double square bracket when you are selecting a list:

```
df[['Adjusted TWR (Current Quarter, No Div, USD)',
                              'Adjusted TWR (YTD, No Div, USD)',
                              'Annualized Adjusted TWR (Since Inception, No Div, USD)']].isnull()
```

This solves the KeyError. However, using this would give you a new error, as this would return you a 2D matrix to pass to df.loc as a parameter, which is an invalid parameter type. Instead, you could filter them one by one.

```
def twr_exceptions_logic():
    df = databases_creation()

    df  = df.loc[(df['Entity/Grouping']!= 'Cash')]
    df  = df.loc[(df['Adjusted TWR (Current Quarter, No Div, USD)'].isnull())]
    df  = df.loc[(df['Adjusted TWR (YTD, No Div, USD)'].isnull())]
    df  = df.loc[(df['Annualized Adjusted TWR (Since Inception, No Div, USD)'].isnull())]
    return df
```